# Android Volley Multidimensional JSON Request post Method

Tags: android, arrays, json, http-post, android-volley

How to send multidimensional array on volley post method.

```
    {
  "code": "001",
    "Emp_id": "0000",
    "Exp_Dt": "2021-05-27T00:00:00.000",
    "users": [
        {
                "id": "1087",
                "name": "Abhishek Saini",
                "email": "info@ezacake.com",
                "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
                "id": "1088",
                "name": "Gourav",
                "email": "gourav9188@gmail.com",
                "gender" : "male"
                
        }
  ]
}
```

This format I want to call API. Please help
Note - I want to Request with array on my API, not a response

Answer (score 2):

hi you are trying to send a json object there =>

create a parent json object

```
JSONObject reqJO = new JSONObject();
```

put other properties eg

```
reqJo.put("code",0001);
```

create a user json object

```
JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
```

put user properties(if more users loop creating new users)eg

```
user.put("id",1087)
```

create a json array of users

```
JSONArray users = new JSONArray();
```

add user in users array

```
users.put(user);
```

put users array in parent object

```
reqJO.put("users",users);
```

Then you continue  with your `JsonObjectRequest`

Comment: Thank you @Lloyd T Mashumba, am created a JSON Array. am try to send pass that value it shows .invalid JSON array. maybe it passing method wrong. please check this code. how to send JSON array. `code` override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                reqJO.put("users",arrayPayLoadRe)
                return params
            } `code`

Comment: The json array is inside object ... try jsonobjectrequest   => new JsonObjectRequest(url,jsonObject,response -> {},error -> {});

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  answer

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest jobReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jObject,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });

queue.add(jobReq);
```